# Restrict application switching using java

Tags: java, desktop-application

I want to develop an JAVA desktop application which opens in Full-screen mode and render some questions and its options from DB.

Fetching data from DB and displaying on label is not the big challenge for me...

But when application get opened I want to restrict user to switch between applications using application traversal keys like (Alt+Tab) etc.

During coding I used `jFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` this keeps application on Top always but when I switch to desktop; my application get minimized and I can access other applications.

also keys like windows+D alos want to restrict or in other words without closing application user will not able to select any other option.

I want to apply all this restrictions independent of platform means if my application run on Linux/Unix then also same behavior ll b there.

Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable/ block Alt+Tab with below code. But you cannot stop user from switching to Desktop with mouse though...

```
  public class AltTabStopper implements Runnable
{
     private boolean working = true;
     private JFrame frame;

     public AltTabStopper(JFrame frame)
     {
          this.frame = frame;
     }

     public void stop()
     {
          working = false;
     }

     public static AltTabStopper create(JFrame frame)
     {
         AltTabStopper stopper = new AltTabStopper(frame);
         new Thread(stopper, "Alt-Tab Stopper").start();
         return stopper;
     }

     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             Robot robot = new Robot();
             while (working)
             {
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                  frame.requestFocus();
                  try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception) {}
             }
         } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dark and @Will one of my suggested that; Do the coding as per os means in `main()` first find os using `System.getProperty("os.name")` then according to os some class will b there like `windowsRestrictions` in that if windows os is there then killing of explorer.exe on `Timer` as u suggested blocking Alt+Tab keypress...Is this okay?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you *can't*.

If you are the administrator of the machine you can configure it to be in *kiosk* mode.  In Windows 8.1 this is getting easier.

But kiosk mode is not something that a third party app can control.  It is something that the user of the computer - who must be savvy - controls.